# Some links not showing properly in uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have links like the below:
http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4186012&mostPopular=&trk=tyah

For some reason uiwebview is not recognizing this links properly. Links without question marks work, but with question marks don't.

Meaning, it does not show the proper linkedin page.

What should I do?

Here's the code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4186012&mostPopular=&trk=tyah";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this: ["UIWebView won't load page."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546381/2371425)?

Here is a link that explains what those question marks in the URL are:
[Query_String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: I would of just commented this instead of making this an "answer" but I don't have 50points yet :/